# Getting wires displayed in OpenGL MeasureIt render

Tags: opengl, wireframe

I'm trying to get a "CAD-like" 2D render of a model in Blender (2.79, sorry old OSX version so can't upgrade) using MeasureIt for dimensions. Some dimensions are to edges within faces.

I've managed to get the OpenGL render to display the wires for the internal edges, but they are removed when I do a MeasureIt OpenGL render. Any ideas how to get them back?

The Viewport (see 'Render' button on the left):
[image: Viewport]

The OpenGL render:
[image: OpenGL]

The MeasureIt OpenGL render:
[image: MeasureIt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution:

- Switch to Wireframe mode
- Enable `World Background` in the Viewport Display options
- Monkey around with the Environment Image/Colour in the Node Editor, World mode

Gives me this - MeasureIt OpenGL render:
[image]